# Ubuntu boots to blinking cursor

Tags: boot, grub2

I tried using Boot-Repair-Disk.  It said to reference:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/B6zJXXhjyk/
and after the boot repair failed to correct the problem ...
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FpS77ytBFW
I've used Ubuntu on this computer since 16.04 came out without any problems until 12-13-2019 when it seemed to freeze up and when I rebooted it wouldn't.  I've tried installing from my 16.04 disks, and from an 18.04.3 flash drive.  I was getting booted to grub rescue, but since then it's always been to the blinking cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Boot Repair could not finish it's work. You will need to email the link to the developers who can advise how to make it finish. Your [Boot Repair link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FpS77ytBFW/) shows:

```
1198  An error occurred during the repair.
```

Here is the [contact information](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Yannubuntu) for Boot Repair. You will need to email them your boot repair links.